# Cannot Connect to QML Emluation Layer (QML Puppet)

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator, qt-quick

I just made the fresh QT installation and when I create empty QT Quick project or open any of existing QT Quick examples, my QML designer doesn't work. It shows "Cannot Connect to QML Emluation Layer (QML Puppet)" error.

I tried to reinstall QT, reboot, installed additional QT kit versions and tried to switch between 32bit/64bit default/opengl versions of the kit and nothing seems to work for me. I was able to successfully run the designer ONCE, and after I closed it and tried to re-open the file it stopped working again. I also tried to search, but didn't find any solution. I also tried to ask on QT forums, but didn't receive any answer.

My system is Windows 7, with Visual Studio 2013 installed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possibly related to [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13029). Just try this workaround: in the Options dialog go to “Qt Quick / Qt Quick Designer / QML Emulation Layer” and disable the checkbox “Always use the QML emulation layer prived by Qt Creator”. That will cause a rebuild of the emulation layer with the used Qt version in the current project. That layer does not crash. This workaround only works with Desktop Kits.

Comment: BaCaRoZzo, I tried this and it didn't work for me (nothing changed). Thank you for your answer anyway!

Comment: Was worth a try, anyway. :) Hope someone else can help you with this strange issue.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo These options aren't available in the latest version of Qt Creator 4.1.0.  I'm able to enter design mode once, but if I try to again I get this error.  Closing and reopening doesn't fix the problem.  Reinstalling does, but the problem just occurs again.  I tried setting a fallback QML emulation layer to this path: C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\qml\qmlpuppet but that didn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

Do this:

- Go to QT Creator **Preferences** (Menu Bar | Tools > Options)
- Select **QT Quick Option** (Options headings - left side).
- Click the **QT Quick Designer** tab.
- Under **QML Emulation Layer** grouping, select "Use QML Emulation Layer that is built with selected QT".

*No need to choose a path*,

- And click **OK**.

It will rebuild your designer view. 
Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Possibly related to this bug. Just try this workaround: in the Options
>   dialog go to “Qt Quick / Qt Quick Designer / QML Emulation Layer” and
>   disable the checkbox “Always use the QML emulation layer prived by Qt
>   Creator”. That will cause a rebuild of the emulation layer with the
>   used Qt version in the current project. That layer does not crash.
>   This workaround only works with Desktop Kits. –  BaCaRoZzo Mar 30

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This worked for me, but still crashed a few times at the outset, when I would switch out of designer mode and back. It started working better after I had been playing with the split view / text-editor / form-editor toggles on the edge of the editor in designer mode. Also, as stated above this only fixes desktop kits.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Tools->Options->Qt Quick.
2. In QML Emulation Layer, make sure
   the path is correct for "Use fallback QML emulation layer".

Since I was reinstalling Qt, the new installation had the old path of Qt which gave rise to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If failed anyway, use **"Qt Design studio"** instead and build it again, it worked for me.

I recommend to uninstall **Qt** first and then reinstall it with  **"Qt Design Studio"** box checked.

On Ubuntu 20 LTS, you can run it on: ***/home/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/bin/qtdesignstudio***

**Good luck.**