# Qt Quick emulator layer crash

Tags: qt, qml

I created an empty QT Quick Application and a **ui.qml** file in the project folder but I'm unable to open the ui file in design mode.
A dialog box describing error message says:

**ine:1: Qt Quick emulator layer crash**

[image: screenshot]

Taking a look at line 1 of the code, i can't find any error

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Page {
        id: page
        width: 200
        height: 200

        Button {
            id: button
        }

        CheckBox {
            id: checkBox
            text: qsTr("Check Box")
        }

        Label {
            id: label
            text: qsTr("Label")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the path for the QML EMULATOR but it didn't solve the issue.

path configurations

[image]

What can be the problem and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error today. But I've successfully fixed it.
You need to do this：**Tool->QT Quick->QT Quick Designer->QML Emulation Layer** , "Use QML Emulation Layer that is built with selected QT"
No need to choose a path,
The solution was first in this thread.
[Cannot Connect to QML Emluation Layer (QML Puppet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290631/cannot-connect-to-qml-emluation-layer-qml-puppet)

Comment: If not working. I suggest adding a QtQuick UI File under the Qt category to this.  This looks like using the new UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Item` to `Rectangle`. Not sure why but it works for me sometimes.